# How to add image counter for this jquery slider?; Number of current images and total

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, counter

Here is my java script code of image slider. I want add image counter with current number of image and number of total images. Any ideas?

```
`jsfiddle.net/AASYC/85`
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aco84/e7z0c5eL/ there is not js code

Comment: thx for replay... i solved that problem, if u can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/AASYC/85/ here is same question how add counter of current image of total images